# How do I remove a query from a url?

Tags: python, url, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to crawl a site which seems to be appending random values to the query string at the end of each URL. This is turning the crawl into a sort of an infinite loop.

How do i make scrapy to neglect the query string part of the URL's?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See [urllib.urlparse](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Example code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse('http://url.something.com/bla.html?querystring=stuff')

url_without_query_string = o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc + o.path
```

Example output:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://url.something.com/bla.html?querystring=stuff')
>>> url_without_query_string = o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc + o.path
>>> print url_without_query_string
http://url.something.com/bla.html
>>>
```

Comment: Should this be: `from urllib.parse import urlparse` ?

Comment: @RyanCady yes `from urllib.parse import urlparse` worked for me.

Comment: @RyanCady: In Python 3, yes, but in Python 2 it should not.

Comment: Don't manually reconstruct. Use `o._replace(query=None).geturl()`

Answer (score 15):

There is a function `url_query_cleaner` in `w3lib.url` module (used by scrapy itself) to clean urls keeping only a list of allowed arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Provide some code, so we can help you.

If you are using `CrawlSpider` and `Rule`'s with `SgmlLinkExtractor`, provide custom function to `proccess_value` parameter of `SgmlLinkExtractor` constructor.

See documentation for [BaseSgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#basesgmllinkextractor)

```
def delete_random_garbage_from_url(url):
    cleaned_url = ... # process url somehow
    return cleaned_url

Rule(
    SgmlLinkExtractor(
         # ... your allow, deny parameters, etc
         process_value=delete_random_garbage_from_url,
    )
)
```

Comment: Both the first and second answercombined seem to solve my problem.I am not sure how i can mark both answers are correct

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`urllib.parse.urlsplit()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). The result is a [*structured parse result*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urlparse-result-object), a named tuple with added functionality.

Use the `namedtuple._replace()` method to alter the parsed result values, then use the [`SplitResult.geturl()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urllib.parse.SplitResult.geturl) to get a URL string again.

To remove the query string, set the `query` value to `None`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

updated_url = urlsplit(url)._replace(query=None).geturl()
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlsplit
>>> url = 'https://example.com/example/path?query_string=everything+after+the+questionmark'
>>> urlparse.urlsplit(url)._replace(query=None).geturl()
'https://example.com/example/path'
```

For Python 2, the same function is available under the [`urlparse.urlsplit()` name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit).

You could also use the [`urllparse.parse.urlparse()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse); for URLs without any [path parameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396.html#section-3.3), the result would be the same. The two functions differ in how path parameters are handled; `urlparse()` only supports path parameters for the last segment of the path, while `urlsplit()` leaves path parameters in place in the path, leaving parsing of such parameters to other code. Since path parameters are rarely used these days [later URL RFCs have dropped the feature altogether), the difference is academical. `urlparse()` uses `urlsplit()` and without parameters, doesn't add anything other than extra overhead. It is better to just use `urlsplit()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BaseSpider, before yielding a new request, remove manually random values from the query part of the URL using [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item_urls = hxs.select(".//a[@class='...']/@href").extract()
    for item_url in item_urls:
        # remove the bad part of the query part of the URL here
        item_url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, item_url)
        self.log('Found item URL: %s' % item_url)
        yield Request(item_url, callback = self.parse_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method to remove query string from url

```
urllink="http://url.something.com/bla.html?querystring=stuff"
url_final=urllink.split('?')[0]
print(url_final)
```

output will be:
http://url.something.com/bla.html